# Get all children page ID's including parent by title

Tags: pages, conditional-content

So I am getting all the children ID's as well as the parent ID to show content only for that page and all its sub-pages. This is the following function I created, but was wondering if there is a better way to do it?

```
function get_all_pages( $page_title ) {

    $page = get_page_by_title( $page_title );

    $pages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $page->ID, 'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc' ) );

    $array = array();

    $array[] = array( 'ID' => $page->ID );

    foreach( $pages as $page ){

        $array[] = array( 'ID' => $page->ID );

    }

    return $array;

}

$allpages = get_all_pages( 'Page Title' );

foreach( $allpages as $page ) {

    if( is_page( $page['ID'] ) ):

        // Show stuff only on these pages

    endif;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done this the hard way. [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) can do most of the work for you.

```
function get_all_pages($page_title) {
  $page = get_page_by_title($page_title);

  if (empty($page)) return array();

  $children = new WP_Query(
    array(
      'post_type' => 'page',
      'post_parent' => $page->ID,
      'fields' => 'ids'
    )
  );
  array_unshift($children->posts,"{$page->ID}");
  return $children->posts;
}

$allpages = get_all_pages('Sample Page');
var_dump($allpages);
```

It is late, and I am sleepy, but I think that duplicates your function with the exception that your code, unnecessarily to my mind, produces nested arrays. My code gives you a "flat" array.

Comment: I actually had changed mine to produce a single dimension array, but your way is much cleaner! Appreciate the response. Forgot about just querying what I needed. Thanks!